# Not able to start hiveserver2 for Apache Hive

Tags: hive

Could any one help to resolve below problem, I'm trying to start hserver2 and I configured hive_site.xml and configuration file for Hadoop Directory path as well and jar file hive-service-rpc-2.1.1.jar also available at directory lib. And I am able to start using hive but not hiveserver2

```
$ hive --service hiveserver2 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /home/directory/Hadoop/Hive/apache-hive-2/1/1-bin/lib/hive-service-rpc-2/1/1/jar
```

Answer (score 0):

export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive-1.2.1/
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive-2.1.1

I am glad that I solve it's problem. Here is my question ,I have different version hive ,and My command use 1.2.1, but it find it's jar form 2.1.1.
you can user command which hive server 2 ,find where is you command from .

Comment: For a new question use 'ask question' button